# how to make command that lists all of the servers the bot is in

Tags: discord, discord.js

I try making a command that I can use to show me the servers the bot is in, but when I start making the command it doesn't work in every way I try it and always tells me that one of the things was not defined or cannot read property mostly it tells me that bot or guilds is not defined or cannot read properly.

*I want to make a command that **only** I can use in discord to see all the servers that my bot is in.*

I use command handler that means that every single command is in separate js file.

My discord client variable is set to "bot" (as shown in the code).

This is the command (servers.js):

```
module.exports = {
    name: 'servers',
    execute(bot, message, args) {
        bot.guilds.cache.forEach(guild => {
            message.channel.send(`Servers: ${guild.name}`);
        })
    }
}
```

This is the command handler/the main file (index.js):

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const bot = new Discord.Client();
const fs = require('fs');
const { prefix, token } = require('./config.json');

    bot.commands = new Discord.Collection();
    const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync('./commands').filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));
    for (const file of commandFiles) {
        const command = require(`./commands/${file}`);
        bot.commands.set(command.name, command);
    }
    const cooldowns = new  Discord.Collection();
    
    bot.once('ready', () => {
        console.log('Online!');
    });
    
    bot.on('message', message => {
        if (!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) return;
            const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).trim().split(/ +/);
            const commandName = args.shift().toLowerCase();
    
            if (!bot.commands.has(commandName)) return;
            const command = bot.commands.get(commandName);
    
            if (command.args && !args.length) {
                    let reply = `You didn't provide any arguments, ${message.author}!`;
    
                    if (command.usage) {
                        reply += `\nThe proper usage would be: \`${prefix}${command.name} ${command.usage}\``;
                    }
                    return message.channel.send(reply);
            }
            try {
                command.execute(message, args);
            }
            catch (error) {
                console.error(error);
                    message.reply('there was an error trying to execute that command!').then(msg => {
                        msg.delete({timeout:6000});
                    });
            }
    });
```

And there is the error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'cache' of undefined
    at Object.execute (D:\Users\USER\Desktop\Bot\commands\serversinfo.js:4:20)
    at Client.<anonymous> (D:\Users\USER\Desktop\Bot\index.js:64:21)
    at Client.emit (node:events:376:20)
    at MessageCreateAction.handle (D:\Users\USER\Desktop\Bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\actions\MessageCreate.js:31:14)
    at Object.module.exports [as MESSAGE_CREATE] (D:\Users\USER\Desktop\Bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\handlers\MESSAGE_CREATE.js:4:32)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your execute function takes 3 arguments `execute(bot, message, args)`, but you are only giving it 2 arguments when you use it in the main file: `command.execute(message, args);`

Adding that missing argument should fix that:

```js
command.execute(bot, message, args)
```

Comment: It worked i just add bot in the brackets in the main file and tried it and worked. Thank you for the help i really appreciate that!

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to list all the servers the bot is in is by mapping all the servers like this:

```
message.channel.send(client.guilds.cache.map(s => s.name))
```

Then you can put it in to your command however needed - Feel free to reply to this if you have any questions or it doesn't work.

```
module.exports = {
name: 'servers',
execute(bot, message, args) {
    message.channel.send(client.guilds.cache.map(s => s.name))
}
```

Please feel free to reply to me if this doesn't work or you have any other questions!

Comment: I tried that but it still don't work it tell me that cannot read property 'send'

Comment: Your suggestion was really helpfull too thanks for the help!

Comment: @TMG if it can't read the property of send then most probably when you put `execute (bot, message, args)` you didn't make message an actual message. If that makes sense